# Proof regarding factorials.

Tags: proof-writing, factorial

Suppose $a$ and $k$ are positive integers, then how would you prove(not intuitively) that:

$a!k! \leq (ak)!$

Although it is apparent that the inequality is correct, but how can I show this algebraically?

Comment: Your conditions are insufficient. A and K need to be *positive* integers, and strictly positive at that: 2! * 0! is not LTE (2*0)!... As for the proof itself, i have a "gut feeling" it can be done using induction, but i haven't (yet) fully worked it out.

Comment: But, induction does the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume $a, k\geq1$.

\begin{align}
\frac {(ak)!} {k!} &= (ak)(ak-1)\cdots(k+1) \\\\
a!&=a(a-1)\cdots2 \\\\
\implies \frac {(ak)!} {a!k!} &= \frac {(ak)(ak-1)\cdots(k+1)}{a(a-1)\cdots2} \geq 1
\end{align}

The numerator has $ak-(k+1)+1=(a-1)k$ terms, while the denominator has $a-1$ terms (which is the same or less by our assumption). Matching each term from the denominator with one from the numerator:

$$ak\geq a\\
ak-1\geq a-1\\
\vdots$$

you get the inequality.

Answer (score 3):

$[1\cdot2\cdot3\dots k][(k+1)\cdot(k+2).\dots (2k)][(2k+1)\cdot(2k+2)\dots (3k)]\dots[(ak-k+1)\cdot(ak-k+2)\dots (ak)]$

$=k!a![(k+1)\cdot(k+2)\cdot\dots (2k-1)(k)][(2k+1)\cdot(2k+2)\dots (k)]\dots [(ak-k+1)\cdot(ak-k+2)\dots (k)]\ge k!a!$

I am taking $1$ from last term of the the first third bracket (1st group of k terms) $2$ from the last term of the 2nd third bracket(2nd group of k terms) , $3$ from the last term of the 3 rd third bracket(3rd group of k terms) and so on to form $a!$

For a more comprehensive answer look at this,

Divide the expression $(mn)!$ into m groups each group consisting of the nos. $\{(kn+1)(kn+2).....((k+1)n)\}$, here k runs from $0$ to $m-1$

So we have ,$\displaystyle (mn)!=\prod_{k=0}^{m-1}(kn+1)(kn+2).....((k+1)n)$

In each group first $n-1$ nos is divisible by $(n-1)!$ as we have m groups so the total product is divisible by $((n-1)!)^m$ (Using the fact that product of $k$ consecutive nos is divisible by $k!$)

Product of the last nos. of the group is $\displaystyle \prod_{k=0}^{m-1}(k+1)n=m!.n^m$

So the whole product is divisible by $((n-1)!)^m.m!.n^m=m!(n!)^m$

Hence proving the fact that $\displaystyle \frac{(mn)!}{m!(n!)^m}$ is an integer.

So $m!n!\le m!(n!)^m\le (mn)!$

Comment: If you use the same \dots for actual dots and multiplication then things are confusing. Use \cdot for multiplication and, if you want, \ldots for three dots. Still, it isn't clear what you did above.

Comment: That's it, but it might not be immediately apparent that you're using the last term of each group of k terms (which is of the form "n.k") and separating it to get the "a!"...

Comment: Now I think its ok @DonAntonio

Comment: Yes, it is now. +1

Answer (score 2):

If $a,k\gt1$ then $(a-1)(k-1)\gt0$; that is, $ak\gt a+k-1$. Since $a,k\in\mathbb{Z}$, we have $ak\ge a+k$.

As an element in [Pascal's Triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle), $\displaystyle\frac{(a+k)!}{a!\,k!}=\binom{a+b}{a}\in\mathbb{Z}$, and since $ak\ge a+k$, we have $\dfrac{(ak)!}{(a+k)!}\in\mathbb{Z}$. Therefore,
$$
\frac{(ak)!}{a!\,k!}=\frac{(a+k)!}{a!\,k!}\frac{(ak)!}{(a+k)!}\in\mathbb{Z}\tag{1}
$$
Since $a!\,k!\mid(ak)!$ and $(ak)!\ne0$, we have that $a!\,k!\le(ak)!$.

Now all we have left to do is handle the case where $a$ or $k$ is $1$. In that case, $a!\,k!=(ak)!$, so we are done.